# Can't search Name and Birthday

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm making Employee Search and delete page at visual force, and I wrote SELECT that I want to search Name or Birthday.

For example, if I search Tom and 20/05/2000, the search result should be Tom and John was born on 20/05/2000.

I wrote SELECT which is

```
'SELECT Employee_Name__c, Employee_Mailaddress__c, Employee_DOB__c  
    FROM Employee_Management__c 
    WHERE Employee_Name__c = \'' + strEmployeeNamec + '\' OR 
          Employee_DOB__c = '+ String.valueOf(info.Employee_DOB__c);
```

However this code is only works to name and not work to birthday. can someone please tell me what's wrong with it . I`m so sorry that my English skill is very poor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I notice my mistakes. I wrote

```
(!!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Name__c) & info.Employee_DOB__c != null)
```

but its should be

```
(!String.IsBlank(info.Employee_Name__c) & info.Employee_DOB__c != null)
```

Comment: As this seems to be a syntax issue you can delete the question and answer the answer related to it.